# Create BigQuery job that creates tables daily

Tags: google-bigquery

we are using BigQuery to store data daily(datarange).
and we are having some performance issues so we would like to create the tables in advanced.
our logic is like this
before inserting to the daily table, we check if the table exist, this take time we cant afford.
also we have dashboards for showing stat, so if we do  select * from datarange table which was not created that day..it will crash.

so we thought, mb the best way is to create daily ,in advanced those daily tables as empty but with the correct structure.
any thoughts ?

Comment: Are you batch loading entire day or increments?